# How to unite two SQL statements when referencing a few tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following TABLES and RECORDS.

```
-- DDL FOR UNIVERSITY EXAMPLE

CREATE TABLE Student    (
stuId       VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY,
lastName    VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL, 
firstName   VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL, 
major       VARCHAR2(10),
credits     NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT Student_credits_cc CHECK ((credits>=0) AND (credits < 150)));

CREATE TABLE Faculty    (
facId       VARCHAR2(6),
name    VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL, 
department  VARCHAR2(20),
rank        VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRAINT Faculty_facId_pk PRIMARY KEY (facId));

CREATE TABLE Class  (
classNumber VARCHAR2(8),
facId   VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES Faculty (facId) ON DELETE SET NULL, 
schedule    VARCHAR2(8),
room        VARCHAR2(6),
CONSTRAINT Class_classNumber_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber), 
CONSTRAINT Class_schedule_room_uk UNIQUE (schedule, room));

CREATE TABLE Enroll (
stuId VARCHAR2(6), 
classNumber VARCHAR2(8), 
grade       VARCHAR2(2),
CONSTRAINT Enroll_classNumber_stuId_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber, stuId),
CONSTRAINT Enroll_classNumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (classNumber) REFERENCES Class (classNumber) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT Enroll_stuId_fk FOREIGN KEY (stuId) REFERENCES Student(stuId) ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1001','Smith','Tom','History',90);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1002','Chin','Ann','Math',36);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1005','Lee','Perry','History',3);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1010','Burns','Edward','Art',63);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1013','McCarthy','Owen','Math',0);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1015','Jones','Mary','Math',42);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('S1020','Rivera','Jane','CSC',15);

INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES('F101','Adams','Art','Professor');
INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES('F105','Tanaka','CSC','Instructor');
INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES('F110','Byrne','Math','Assistant');
INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES('F115','Smith','History','Associate');
INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES('F221','Smith','CSC','Professor');

INSERT INTO CLASS VALUES('ART103A','F101','MWF9','H221');
INSERT INTO CLASS VALUES('CSC201A','F105','uThF10','M110');
INSERT INTO CLASS VALUES('CSC203A','F105','MThF12','M110');
INSERT INTO CLASS VALUES('HST205A','F115','MWF11','H221');
INSERT INTO CLASS VALUES('MTH101B','F110','MTuTh9','H225');
INSERT INTO CLASS VALUES('MTH103C','F110','MWF11','H225');

INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1001','ART103A','A');
INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1001','HST205A','C');
INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1002','ART103A','D');
INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1002','CSC201A','F');
INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1002','MTH103C','B');
INSERT INTO ENROLL(stuId,classNumber) VALUES('S1010','ART103A');
INSERT INTO ENROLL(stuId,classNumber) VALUES('S1010','MTH103C');    
INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1020','CSC201A','B');
INSERT INTO ENROLL VALUES('S1020','MTH101B','A');

--Figure 5.1
```

I need to answer the following query: Find the names of all the teachers that Ann Chin has, along with all her classes and midterm grades from each.

So far, I have tried many SELECT combinations, but I keep getting duplicate values and returns.

This is the closest I have come:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT FACULTY.NAME FROM FACULTY WHERE FACULTY.FACID in (SELECT DISTINCT FACID FROM CLASS WHERE CLASSNUMBER in (SELECT DISTINCT CLASSNUMBER FROM ENROLL WHERE STUID in (SELECT DISTINCT STUID FROM STUDENT WHERE FIRSTNAME='Ann' and LASTNAME='Chin')));

NAME
--------------------
Byrne
Adams
Tanaka

SQL> SELECT ENROLL.CLASSNUMBER, ENROLL.GRADE
  2  FROM ENROLL
  3  WHERE STUID in (SELECT STUID FROM STUDENT WHERE FIRSTNAME='Ann' and LASTNAME='Chin');

CLASSNUM GR
-------- --
ART103A  D
CSC201A  F
MTH103C  B
```

I basically need to do what these two statements do separately together.
Can you please tell me how?

Comment: On a side note: Only use `DISTINCT` when necessary. It definitely isn't necessary for `IN` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use INNER JOINs here:

```
SELECT e.CLASSNUMBER,
       e.GRADE,
       f.NAME
  FROM STUDENT s
  INNER JOIN ENROLL e
    ON e.STUID = s.STUID
  INNER JOIN CLASS c
    ON c.CLASSNUMBER = e.CLASSNUMBER
  INNER JOIN FACULTY f
    ON f.FACID = c.FACID
  WHERE s.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || s.LASTNAME = 'Ann Chin'
  ORDER BY e.CLASSNUMBER
```

This produces:

```
CLASSNUMBER GRADE   NAME
ART103A     D       Adams
CSC201A     F       Tanaka
MTH103C     B       Byrne
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=119e6e06c985830ca71e83c34bc08b01)

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the tables. I don't know from your description how to get midterm grades. Can this somehow be determined from the `schedule` string?

```
select
  f.name as teacher_name,
  c.classnumber as class,
  e.grade as midterm_grade
from enroll e
join class c on c.classnumber = e.classnumber
join faculty f on f.facid = c.facid
where e.stuid = (select stuid from student where firstname = 'Ann' and lastname = 'Chin')
order by f.name, c.classNumber;
```

Comment: ENROLL.GRADE is the only grade available so I believe that is midterm grade.

Comment: The proposed solution gives the following ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry. I had `USING` instead of `ON`, because I started with `USING` clauses. I've removed the midterm thing from my query. I thought there must be some way to retrieve this from the schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS instead of subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.NAME, e.CLASSNUMBER, e.GRADE
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN ENROLL e ON e.STUDID = s.STUDID
JOIN CLASS c ON c.CLASSNUMBER = e.CLASSNUMBER
JOIN FACULTY f ON f.FACIC = c.FACID
WHERE s.FIRSTNAME='Ann' and s.LASTNAME='Chin'
```

Comment: PLease explain why you are using `DISTINCT`. `JOIN [CLASS]` is invalid. You can use brackets around names in SQL Server and MS Access, as far as I know. You can't use them in standard SQL or Oracle for that matter.

Comment: I am a SQL server user and did not know about the brackets not working when using Oracle. Thanks for correcting me. I updated my answer. I included the brackets since CLASS seems to be an SQL keyword. 
I specifically did just join both the queries the OP provided in this answer, as that was what the OP asked for. Since the OP included DISTINCT in them I left that in, but I think you are right in thinking that it might not be needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.classnumber,
      a.grade,
      d.NAME
FROM ENROLL a,
     STUDENT b
     CLASS c,
     FACULTY d
where a.stuid = b.stuid(+)
and e.classnumber = c.classnumber(+)
and c.facid = f.facid(+)
and s.firstname = 'Ann'
and s.lastname = 'Chin'
order by 1
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.